# CSS3: flex transition doesn't work anymore since Safari 13.1 (Mac)

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, css-transitions

Here is the simplest code that works on every modern browser (and also on very recent safari browsers) but not on the v.13.1 that I just updated on my Mac.

The point is to get a section to expand when hovering it while the other sections remain equally large. Simple enough.
Everything works on Safari 13.1 (it expands alright) except the animation of the flex transition.

On Safari 13.1 it is abrupt while on any other browser, Chrome/Firefox/older Safari included, the transition is smooth.

Any fix or workaround (based on flex) please?

Thank you.

```css
section {
  height: 200px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
}

.color {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: flex 500ms;
}

.color:hover {
  flex: 1 1 40em;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

  <section class="color" style="background: red"></section>

  <section class="color" style="background: blue"></section>

  <section class="color" style="background: green"></section>

  <section class="color" style="background: yellow"></section>

  <section class="color" style="background: orange"></section>

</div>
```

**Additional note**: I know that replacing flex transition with (min-)width transitions works but it implies some undesired side effects as it becomes complex very quickly when borders and paddings come into play, especially when the website is responsive, the amount of sections is dynamic and one needs a precision to the pixel. Flex is very straight forward in that regard as everything is taken care of by design. I learned it the hard way by testing every other solutions for weeks and ruling them out one by one when blocking issues appeared along the way.
With the example here above, width transitions would work seamlessly but this is just the minimal use case to show the flex issue, not my final script that is way more complex and which doesn't comply with width transitions very well (and that's an understatement).

That's why I need to stick with the flex transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed this `transition: all 500ms;` and it work for my mac safari.

```css
section {
  height: 200px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
}

.color {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.color:hover {
  flex: 1 1 40em;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

  <section class="color" style="background: red"></section>

  <section class="color" style="background: blue"></section>

  <section class="color" style="background: green"></section>

  <section class="color" style="background: yellow"></section>

  <section class="color" style="background: orange"></section>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this ! Just FYI: I implemented your hack in my original script after your answer and it still didn't work ('transition: all 0.4s;'). Then I saw it was in seconds, which worked just fine before by the way but, just to be sure, I changed it to ''transition: all 400ms;' instead and now it works :-)
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is there some value between `flex` and `all` that will still animate? It's not `flex-basis`, either.